# Python: Looking for a specific value in array column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a specific integer value `k` and I want to find matching values in a column of a 2d numpy array (using a "for" loop).
I thought I could use an `if` statement and directly compare the single array element with the integer value `k`.
Here is my code:

```
for i in range(mock.shape[0]):

    n_cl = int(mock[i,0]/3500.)
    zcl = mock[i,5]
    pick = [np.random.random_integers(200, size=(n_cl))]
    print pick[0]   
    if(zcl <= 0.05):

        for k in range(len(pick)) :

            for j in range(z_001.shape[0]):
                n = z_001[j,1]
                if (int(n) == pick[k]):
                    binaries[j,7] = mock[i,0]   
                    binaries[j,8] = mock[i,1]
                    binaries[j,9] = mock[i,2]
                    binaries[j,10] = mock[i,3]
                    binaries[j,11] = mock[i,4]
```

I always get a ValueError about the truth value of an array with more than one element, which is ambiguous. I understand that the problem is in " int(n) == k", but
I wonder where am I wrong, and how could I put things better and make this part of my code work.

Comment: Where is `i` defined?

Comment: likely `n` and `k` are arrays, not simple numbers. Check out this piece of code, that raises the same error: `if (array([1,1])==array([1,3])): print 'foo'`

Comment: They are. n is an element of a 2d array, k an element of a list.

Comment: It's very difficult to help when we don't know what `pick`, `i`, `binaries`, `mock`, etc. all are. You'll get much more help if you can get closer to a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How can I compare a single member of an array , let's say a[i,j] to an integer number?

Comment: @Alessandra Ferri: I don't think that `n` and `k` are elements, I think they are arrays.Try printing both of them just before the `if` clause. And try to understand the code in my previous comment.

Comment: if I print "type(n)" I get numpy.float64. I should have reported a bigger part of the code

Comment: and what happens when you print `type(k)`?

Comment: ok, the problem is k. I get numpy.ndarray..I tought that while iterating on a list (pick), each element of the list was considered a single number.  here is how I defined the list:   pick = [np.random.random_integers(200, size=(20))]

Comment: Use simply `k=np.random.random_integers(200, size=(20))` without the additional brackets `[]`. If this solves the issue, post it as an answer trying to explain why the error occurred and your solution. welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, consider:

1. whenever you are using numpy, you probably don't want to use for loops
2. The error you get means that you are comparing an numpy array to a single value

So, one possible solution to the problem could be:

```
import numpy as np

# generating some fake data
x = np.repeat([[1,2,3,4]], 4, axis=0) 
x[2,2] = 200
x[3,1] = 200

# retrieving the indices where "x==200" using np.where
indices = np.where(x==200)
print indices
```

which gives:

```
(array([2, 3]), array([2, 1]))
```

so you can just index any other array (with appropriate shape) with `indices` 
and you will get the value of that array in the `indices` positions.

Comment: numpy is exactly what I thought to use.  It provides the access,sorting, and querying one needs to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by changing the `pick` list definition, from `pick = [np.random.random_integers(200, size=(n_cl))]` to `pick = np.random.random_integers(200, size=(n_cl))`.

The problem occurred because I had been comparing an array value to an integer value.